# Access Application.OpenForms via foreach vs. index

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, collections

I just stumpled over this issue and I'm curious why it is that way:
If I access a form in the collection of `Application.OpenForms` via index the compiler tells me it is a form:

```
var form = Application.OpenForms[0];
form.Name = "A new name";
```

This works perfectly fine. But if I access it like this:

```
foreach (var form in Application.OpenForms)
{
  form.Name = "A new name";
}
```

The complier tells me `form` is an object. Why is it this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get objects in foreach loop because `FormCollection` class implements **non-generic** [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.readonlycollectionbase.getenumerator.aspx) interface (inherited from ReadOnlyCollectionBase). But it has indexer which returns `Form`.

Simply cast objects to `Form` type in loop:

```
foreach (Form form in Application.OpenForms)
{
   form.Name = "A new name";
}
```

Comment: Ah okay, thank you. So there is no problem "casting" it always to `Form` right?

Comment: @derape exactly, simply cast object to form like this `foreach(Form form in Application.OpenForms)`

Answer (score 0):

If you'll check [`Application.OpenForms`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms.aspx) Property, its value was defined by "A `FormCollection` containing all the currently open forms owned by this application". Which `FormCollection` was inherited from [`ReadOnlyCollectionBase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.readonlycollectionbase.aspx), then every instance in a collection were defined as an object. So can either cast it to a `Form` to use it, or just use `Form` in the `foreach` loop than using `var`.